# Syncing org files under version control and MobileOrg

Tags: org-mode, git, mobileorg

I have a setup in which I keep my .org files in a git repo, with one fork in my laptop and other in my office computer (whose filesystem I can access remotely always). I recently set up MobileOrg in my phone (to work with my laptop) and am loving it. I am using Dropbox for synchronization. I would like to also be able to pull/push from my phone from my work computer. What is the best way of setting this up?
I would normally just use the same Dropbox folder in my work computer and link the corresponding org folder. However, I am worried about conflicts when later merging, pulling, pushing between the original forks, after MobileOrg has changed both. Will git and MobileOrg be able to graciously handle these?